# Deleting identical rows in matrix

Tags: c, math, matrix

Can someone help me out with this problem? What is the fastest way to delete identical rows in  matrix. E.g. if there are 3 identical rows, 2 will be deleted.

e.g.

> > 0 1 0
> >     0 1 0
> >     0 1 0
> >     1 1 1

will be

> > 0 1 0
> >     1 1 1

Comment: Describe how you're storing the matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the rows of the matrix based upon a well defined ordering (e.g. [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)) and then compare adjacent rows removing duplicates as they are found.  If you need to restore the original row ordering, you can track the row permutation you induce through the sorting and then reverse that permutation once you have  eliminated the duplicate 
rows.

Performing any kind of pairwise comparison without sorting will be of O(N<sup>2</sup>) time complexity to locate duplicates, whereas sorting first will be of O(N log N) time complexity, where N is the number of rows.

If you have questions about the specifics of your implementation, you will need to let us know what you've tried so far and describe how it falls short of your expectations.